# Generating Submit Button with Ajax Not Submitting Form Data

Tags: php, ajax

**Resolved:**  I had $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'post' as lowercase.  That has to be capital apparently... It worked as soon as I capitalized it, and that was the only change.  I voted you up for you fine chaps who helped.  Thanks!

I'm generating a submit button after a simple math question with Ajax.  The Ajax works fine.  I can verify with var_dump/print_r that the $_POST and the $_SESSION data is being passed correctly.  The submit button is going in the output div like I would expect.

However, when I press the submit button, it reloads the page but it does not trigger a submit.  It goes back to the form and the $_POST variable is empty / not set at all.

The submit button is in the form tags.  Why is it submitting the form but not the data / how do I get it to work?

I don't think you need the code to answer the question, but nonetheless, here is a simplified version of the code:

```
// In a server request method block on test.php:
     if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' ){
<form  id="addUserId"  name="addUser"  method="post"  action="test.php" >
<table id="formCreatoraddUserIdTableId"  cellpadding="2"  cellspacing="2"  width="100%" >
    <tr id="formCreatorRowId0" >
        <td valign="top" ><font>3 minus 1: </font></td>
        <td valign="top" ><input type="text"  id="validatorId"  name="validate"  onkeyup="makeAjaxRequest('./ajax/captchaSubmitButtonCheck.php', 'captcha='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('validatorId').value),'captchaOutputDiv', '1');" autocomplete="off"  />          
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="formCreatorRowId1" >
        <td valign="top" ><font></font></td>
        <td valign="top" >
            <div  id="captchaOutputDiv" ></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <input type="hidden"  name="refreshPostPrevention"  />
</form>
   }else{

     print_r( $_POST ); // will be empty
   }
     // in an ajax file captchaSubmitButtonCheck.php:
<?PHP
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
    printr( $_POST );
    printr( $_SESSION, 'SESSION' );
    if( $_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha'] ){
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Save" />';    
    }else{
        echo '<font class="red">Your math was wrong. Try again.</font>';    
    }
}
?>

     // the JS

function makeAjaxRequest(url, params, output, image) {
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if( image == 1 ){
      document.getElementById(output).innerHTML='<img src="./images/template/ajax-loader.gif"></img>'; 
  }
  if(xmlhttp) { 
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById(output).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element 
         }
         else {
            alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
         }
       }    
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(params); //Posting txtname to PHP File
  }
}
```

Comment: See my answer below, but where is the submit button in your code? And what do you attempt to show with <input type='input'/> do you mean <input type='submit'/>? Check: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: There was a type-o in the validator name.  It was suppose to be input type="text" not input type="input".  It's late.  The submit button appears in the captchaOutputDiv after the ajax processes.

Comment: the only JS is makeAjaxRequest function, which just links to your very standard ajax requests.  No jquery or anything else special.

Comment: `printr( $_POST )` and `printr( $_SESSION, 'SESSION' );` it should be `print_r()`;

Comment: printr is a function I have for echo '<pre>'; print_r(); echo '</pre>';  just saving some typing

Comment: ic, and its something new for me ;-). +1 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use AJAX driven interfaces, you may not want to use a submit button, only display a submit button as a fallback when JS is disabled. Because when you put a submit button inside a form it will always try to submit, unless you explicitely prevent it from doing so by overriding the submit action on the form.

My solution is to just use a normal input type='button' or any element actually that performs the AJAX action onClick, and then submit the form data either with [serialization](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  or manually sent the data to the AJAX script. That way you also have more control over what is being sent and how.

//Using jQuery

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var data  = $("form").serialize();
    //Ajax code here
}

<span class='action' onclick='ajaxSubmit'>Send the data</a>
```

Or overwriting the submit action, with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm not passing all of the form data to ajax.  I'm still using the form action to go to a new instance of the page to process the data.  I am using the ajax just to turn a submit button on.  It doesn't have to be a submit button.  It could be a button with form.submit() in the onclick.  Either way, I get the same result.  It's maddening because I do this and it works on another site, but it's not working here (same host/ same setup...)

Comment: Right. Have you tried hiding the submit button instead of adding it in the HTML via AJAX. And then showing it when the Captcha is passed? That might solve the problem because then the submit button is inside the form tags from the start, instead of being added later.

Comment: I was trying that now.  I don't think the ajax will affect the dom elements like that.  At least, I couldn't put javascript in the ajax and get it to even give me an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `makeAjaxRequest();`  is post method ?

Comment: Yes, I added it so you can see too.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and fixed it finally .One thing I have noticed in jQuery Ajax captcha If we manually submit the form  after ajaxCaptcha validation the $_POST variable will not have type="submit" object in the result, In this case we could not validate in the server side  with submit button name, we can validate with captcha name.

In my case $_POST had all the values which is above my captcha text box.

Answer (score -1):

The submit button is outside of the form; an empty form is being created around it implicitly to make the HTML valid.

Put your button *inside* the form that it's supposed to submit.

<sup>(Also, I think you meant `input type="text"` for the CAPTCHA.)</sup>

Comment: The submit is going inside of the captcha output div, which is inside of the form tags.  It's not outside.  You are correct on the input type="text".  It's just late.

Comment: @phpmeh: No it's not. I can't pass it in an atomic fashion to jsfiddle.net and see the issue in front of my eyes. I have to mess around faking PHP files, guessing things, and whatnot. Break down the issue into its components.

Comment: @phpmeh: Then the question is not supposed to be on this website, which is for _code-based_ questions about programming languages.

Comment: You're honestly going to try to tell me that the question above doesn't fit on stackoverflow?  I really do appreciate you trying to help, but go help someone else now.

Comment: @phpmeh: That is correct. Conceptual questions do not belong here. Read the FAQ.