# $_FILES returning empty string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's my form code

```
html += `</div>
        <div class="card-footer">
        <form id="messageSendDashboardGroup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image-upload">
        <div class="input-group" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="${name}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="prefix" value="${prefix}" />
        <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-append">
        <label for="file-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <span class="input-group-text" style="height: 100%;"><i class="fa 
         fa-upload"></i></span>
        <span><input id="file-input" type="file" name="image"></span>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>`;
    $('.empChatMessagesShowHere').append(html);
```

It will generate the form

```
$('#messageSendDashboardGroup').on('submit', function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'dashboard/image_api',
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) 
        {
           console.log(data);
        }
});
```

In my controller when i debug $_FILES its returning emtpy array

```
function image_api()
{
    debug($_FILES);
}

Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

I have tried many things but still i am getting an empty $_FILES array kindly help me please, i am using this form to upload image.

Comment: Look at DevTools what your script send to server

Comment: i am getting empty $_FILES array at my server side

Comment: yes, so inspect your frontend code.

Comment: i did but not getting any help

Comment: by the way, type 'post' .. shouldn't be in single quotes.

Comment: Error code 4 means there was no file uploaded.
Refer to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan doesn't matter i check all form data before ajax call but image still empty.

Comment: can you post your POST request headers from DevTools ?

Comment: Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)

Comment: hmm .. maybe you can find your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560245/generating-submit-button-with-ajax-not-submitting-form-data. Also, did you try to send serialize for data? Maybe your var formData is not formed properly. Can you console.log that?

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan — console.loging a FormData object won't reveal anything useful.

Comment: The most likely explanation I can think of for this problem is that you didn't pick a file with the file input before running the JS that reads the data from the form.

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan — The value of `type` needs to be a string. Single quotes are a perfectly fine way to delimit string literals in JS.

Comment: "In my controller when i debug $_FILES its returning emtpy array" — Where, exactly, are you reading that response from? The Console? The Network tab? Either of those should be fine, but I've seen people follow up an Ajax request with a manual GET request and wonder why they don't see the POST data from their Ajax request in the response to the GET request.

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan i console log and it also returning empty name of file,

Comment: @Quentin i am getting response in my network

Answer (score -1):

I Just change my code to this and it works

```
html += `</div>
        <div class="card-footer">
        <form id="messageSendDashboardGroup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image-upload">
        <div class="input-group" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="${name}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="prefix" value="${prefix}" />
        <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>`;
    $('.empChatMessagesShowHere').append(html);
```

Before i am using input-prepend button for file upload now i am using default file upload button and it works.